# Two canvases at same absolute position, how to force mouse focus to the top one

Tags: html

I have two canvases exactly at same position, the first adCanvas is used to draw a video ad before a game is loaded to another div. When the video ad ends,  I show the game and move focus to mainCanvas simply with a command adCanvas.style.display="none";

Currently for some reason the mainCanvas has the mouse focus all the time, so clicking the video ads  does not work at all.  Clicking of game is ok.

```
 <canvas style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:2"
 id="adCanvas" width="660" height="440"></canvas> <canvas
 style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1"
 id="mainCanvas"  width="660" height="440"></canvas>
```

I also tried to use pointer-events:none but failed.  This game is inside iframe.

The reason to use two canvases is that for some reason game does not load if there is one common canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mainCanvas` is on top of `adCanvas` (i.e. a higher `z-index`) so it will accept any mouse clicks if it is visible.

I'm guessing `mainCanvas` is transparent (otherwise you wouldn't be able to see `adCanvas` anyway, right?) at this point so why not hide it the same way you are hiding `adCanvas` and show it once the video has finished?